# Getting error every time after assign interface to Object - Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types

Getting error after assigning an interface to any object in typescript.

I have two below interface.

```
export interface UserInfo {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    lastUpdateTime: string,
    status: string
}

export interface User{
    activeCount: string,
    subsource: string,
    users: UserInfo[]
}
```

After assign the above User interface to an object in a component getting error.

```
user: User= {}; // Type {} is missing the properties 
user: User;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make properties optional by using the `Partial` utility type.

```
const user: Partial<User> = {};
```

Or do the same thing manually by mapping the properties.

```
interface UserInfo {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    lastUpdateTime: string;
    status: string;
}

interface User {
    activeCount: string;
    subsource: string;
    users: UserInfo[];
}

export type MakeOptional<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] };

const user: MakeOptional<User> = {};
```

This would be a more generic solution for your problem.

Comment: TS has Partial utility type that does exactly that. Partial<User> will just make all properties optional.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about that. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its because when you specify a property of the type like this  `firstName: string` the property should be present (its required) please change its definition to `firstName?: string,` which means the property is an optional property and can be not defined!

Then the error will go away!

```
export interface UserInfo {
    firstName?: string,
    lastName?: string,
    lastUpdateTime?: string,
    status?: string
}

export interface User{
    activeCount?: string,
    subsource?: string,
    users?: UserInfo[]
}
```

After assign the above User interface to an object in a component getting error.

```
user: User= {}; // Type {} is missing the properties - wont come now! 
user: User;
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you need to add the properties to the object:

```
const user: User = {
  users: [],
  activeCount: "",
  subsource: "",
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to tell the compiler that {} is a type of User and contains the same properties as the User interface. For example:

```
user:User = {} as User;
```

Answer (score 0):

as per typescript,
You Define **user: User**  it set value of user as User
to use interface you have to define like : **let user: User**